# A $C^1$-function, s.t. approximation by the Trapezoidal rule is more accurate than by Simpson's rule?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, numerical-methods

> Find values $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and a function $f \in C^{1}[a,b]$, such that the approximation of $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$ by the Trapezoidal rule $T(f)$ is better than the approximation by the Simpson rule $S(f)$.

It's well-known, that $T(f)$ is exact for all polynomials of degree $\leq 1$ and $S(f)$ is exact even for all polynomials with degree $\leq 3$. So, if there's a polynomial with the property in question than it must be of degree higher than $3$. However, I was unable to find such a polynomial. I tried different combinations of $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x), \exp(x)$ on symmetric and non-symmetric intervals but to no avail. Fortunately, it's very easy to check a candidate function with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simpson%27s%20rule%20x*cos(x%5E2)%20from%20-1%20to%201) (c.f. Method comparison).

I guess the brute-force approach doesn't work here. There's probably some property of $T(f)$ and $S(f)$ which can be exploited to give the desired result, but I just can't figure it out! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like $f(x) = 10 e^{-100 x^2}$ on $[-1,1]$

The idea is that the Simpson's rule weight heavily the middle point, so if your function is nearly constant but has a very narrow and high spike at the middle point, it will be worse than just taking the endpoints